# How to access database from another PC in LAN using C#

Tags: c#-4.0, sql-server-2005

I am making a Windows application using C# .I have two machines connected on lan. On one machine database is stored and i want to access that database from other machine .How can i do that??Please help me

Comment: in your connection string specify Data Source to be the IP,port of the machine where SQLServer is residing

Comment: ConnectionString="Data Source=192.168.100.199;Initial Catalog=ImageProcessdb;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 cacthes on your connection string:

1. Using Windows Athentication may not work for you since your are attempting to connect from a different PC, thus the Windows User will most cerntainly be different
2. You dont specify the port of the SQL Server

So:

1. Use Integrated Security=false and provide Username and pswd on your con string
2. Add the prot of SQL Server (you can find it from SQL Configuration Manager)

Finally: 
Your con string should look like:

```
ConnectionString="Data Source=192.168.100.199,PortNumber;Initial Catalog=ImageProcessdb;User ID=myUSer;password=myPass;Integrated Security=False;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True; providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

Comment: thanks dear bt still getting error like Login failed for user 'myUSer'.

Comment: Just want to clarify: you dont use myUSer and myPass as values, you change it to the real values you got in your DB, right?

Comment: If indeed the credentials you are using exist on the SQL Server residing in IP 192.168.100.199, I cant understand why your are getting this error...